# Why does JavaScript interprets numbers with 16 decimal places as "integer"?

Tags: javascript, integer, modulus

Calculating if the modulus of a number is 0 to find if the number is whole works up until 15 decimal places is exceeded.

What makes 0.9999999999999999 diferent from 0.99999999999999999

```
function isInteger(n) {
    return n % 1 === 0;
}

isInteger(0.9); //false
isInteger(0.99999999999999999); //true?
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duyzLps8/) example

Why is this?

Comment: It is rounded to 1 due to float precision.

Comment: Try `console.log(0.99999999999999999)` and see for yourself.

Comment: Why does it round up at 16 decimal places?